# How long does it take to get approval after you support your app info to the app center? We've been waiting for about 2 weeks now.

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

How long does it take to get approval after you support your app info to the app center? We've been waiting for about 2 weeks now. Not sure if anyone has a brief timeline of how this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently a large number of applications in review, so I apologize for the wait.
You will get an email when your app has been scheduled for technical review, and it takes only a few days. However if there are any issues they may be required to be resolved before moving on to the Security review.

If you want to message me, I can take a look at where your application is in the queue.

regards,
Jarred Keneally

Comment: You can see more info here: https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/177500-how-long-does-it-take-to-go-through-technical-review-and-security-review